# How do i group more ArrayLists in one variable?

Tags: java, arraylist, jxl

I have this constructor in another class

```
  public <T> initializingWorkbook( Sheet sheet,List <T> column, int index) 
 {
    int rows = sheet.getRows();
        for(int row = 1;row < rows;row++)
        {
            String i = sheet.getCell(index, row).getContents();
            coloana.add(Double.parseDouble(i)) ;
        }
 }
```

In the main() function I have to initialize all those Arrays at once. So when I call the initializingWorkbook() function I want all these arrays to be filled with data (I'm taking that data from an excel file).

```
ArrayList <Long> timeColumn = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList <Double> pc1Column = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList <Double> pc2Column = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList <Double> ph1Column = new ArrayList<>(); 
ArrayList <Double> ph2Column = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList <Double> ph3Column= new ArrayList<>();
```

Edit: I added what this constructor contains. So basically
      -`Sheet sheet` is the sheet from where I read data;
      -`List <T> column` is the variable where I stock the column;
      -`index` is the number of the column.
I need to load all data in my ArrayList variables at once.
 Thanks for your answers.

Comment: What do you mean with group?

Comment: you have already initialized the lists, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe make an Array of ArrayLists? (ArrayList<Double>[] columns) or (ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> columns)

Comment: Are the entries in the lists related? Does the first entry in timeColumn belong to pc1Column and you are trying to print it as a table?

Comment: I think you put a similar question the other day, right? And because of it being unclear, it got closed, and you got downvotes. So you probably deleted it. And you were told to study the [help] to understand how to ask **better** questions. Hint: this question is not all better than the last one. Hint 2: give more context, show the code you already created. We can only **guess** what you intend to do; and that is **not** how it works over here ... SO: when you get negative feedback, then **improve** your input; instead of just deleting and trying again.

Comment: Yeah I asked a similar question yesterday too, but i didn't get any down vote. So I don't know how to make this more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to represent a table, aren't you?

You could create a class for one record in the table, and store an ArrayList of this class.

```
public class MyClass {
    public Long timeColumn;
    public Double pc1Column;
    public Double pc2Column;
    public Double ph1Column;
    public Double ph2Column;
    public Double ph3Column;
}
```

You create the ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<MyClass> myTable = new ArrayList<>();
```

You add an element like this:

```
for(every row in the table) {
     String cell1 = sheet.getCell(0, row).getContents();
     String cell2 = sheet.getCell(1, row).getContents();
     String cell3 = sheet.getCell(2, row).getContents();
     String cell4 = sheet.getCell(3, row).getContents();
     String cell5 = sheet.getCell(4, row).getContents();
     String cell6 = sheet.getCell(5, row).getContents();

     MyClass record = new MyClass();
     record.timeColumn = Long.parseLong(cell1);
     record.pc1Column = Double.parseDouble(cell2);
     record.pc2Column = Double.parseDouble(cell3);
     record.ph1Column = Double.parseDouble(cell4);
     record.ph2Column = Double.parseDouble(cell5);
     record.ph3Column = Double.parseDouble(cell6);

     myTable.add(record);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I got this error(on the coloana.add line) saying `The method add(MyClass) in the type ArrayList<MyClass> is not applicable for the arguments (double)`

`public initializareWorkbook( Sheet sheet, ArrayList<MyClass> coloana, int index) 
 {
     int rows = sheet.getRows();
      for(int row = 1;row < rows;row++)
      {
       String i = sheet.getCell(index, row).getContents();
    coloana.add(Double.parseDouble(i)) ;
      }
 }`

Comment: @Catalin You are trying to add a double. First you need to create the `MyClass` object, set its member fields to the record's values, and add that. You can try adding a constructor, or you can do it with getters/setters too, but you should make your members private in that case. Also, please come up with a better name than "MyClass", something that suits your data. :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be a List of lists, then access them by index. Another option would be to put them in a Map. The choice would be dependent on how you plan to load the data and use it later.

Note, there is no need to use a concrete type, the generic one would be enough and it is also preferred.

```
List<Object> listOfObj = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: If there is no need to use Object, dont use it in generics.

Comment: @Wietlol Used Object to show that you can put anything in there.

Comment: Can you explain more? Like with some code on my example.